# Notepad++ replace .|every 5th line with .}

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I got a text that ends on every single line with `.|`

And I need to replace the `.|` on every 5th line with `.}`

I did it with this code in search `(((.|)*\s*\s*){5})` and replace `$1.}`

But that adds every 5th line a new line with  `.}` on the beginning, but doesn't replace the `.|` on the end of the 5th.

And I can't figure out how to modify the code for my need!

Maybe some modification ideas for this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

Fin what: `((?:.+\R){4}.+)\|(\R)`
Replace with: `$1}$2`

Then clic on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Make sure that `Dot matches newline` is NOT checked.

Comment: That works! Great! I spend hours without any solution. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

1.Put the cursor in front of the first letter of the whole text

2.Click "Start Recording"

3.Press Down Arrow 4 times

4.Press End once

5.Press Backspace once

6.Press } once

7.Press Right Arrow once

8.Click "Stop Recording"

10.Click "Run a Macro Multiple Times..."

11.Select "Run until the end of file"

12.Click "Run"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but looking for for matching lines and then a nother line that matches up to the point you want to replace.

With regex and wraparound checked and ". matches newline" not checked, searchign forward form start of file.

search:

```
((^.*\.\|\r\n){4}(^.*))\.\|\r\n
```

That 4 times form the start of a line match all characters including the .| at the EoL and alos match all the characters on the next line up to the .| at the EoL.

replace:

\1.}\r\n

Replace everything in the 1st capture group with itself followed by you new end of line sequence.